# Converting existing css/html page into Django

Tags: jquery, python, html, css, django

I have a jQuery/CSS/html webpage. I wanted to add some backend with Python/Django.
I put that page (index.html) + all dependent css and js files into the templates folder (inside the Django project folder).
I added the address to that page to the urls.py file and models.py file.
When I run the server and try to access that page, it displays but without css styles and javascript code. So, it seems like it misses taking css and js files from that html webpage. What's wrong? What I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Django, the static files are separated from the main web page templates. See [the documentation on static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use `{% static %}` method with every CSS and JS reference.

If `href = "stackoverflow.jpeg"` then adjust your code as follows :

```
href = "{% static 'stackoverflow.jpeg'%}"
```

Do the same with every piece of JS and CSS code.